# Filtering fields with same properties as Laravel Releationship HasMany

Tags: php, laravel

I am preparing an e-commerce site. I have two tables linked by Releationship. The first table is Products and the second is ProductAttributes.
It is linked by product_id in two tables. When I query my Products table, in my Product model file

```php
public function attributes()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ProductAttribute::class, 'product_id');
}
```

I want to extract only eligible products using relation. The query is like this:

```php
$products = Product::select('id', 'slug', 'p_image', 'name', 'active', 'low_sell_price', 'combine_name')
    ->where('active', 'a')
    ->whereHas('categories', function ($query) {
        $query->where('slug->tr', $this->slug);
    })
    ->whereHas('attributes' , function ($attrquery) {
        $attrquery->whereIn('value', $this->select_filter_attr);
    })
    ->paginate(100);
```

But the problem is, when I do `whereIn('value' , ['2021','LOW'])` using the value field in the `ProductAttributes` table, it pulls all the products with both 2021 and LOW values, while I want it to pull the products with both 2021 and LOW fields at the same time. How do I do this, thanks in advance.

Comment: how can something have both of those values at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this like this:

```
$products = Product::select('id', 'slug', 'p_image', 'name', 'active', 'low_sell_price', 'combine_name')
    ->where('active', 'a')
    ->whereHas('categories', function ($query) {
        $query->where('slug->tr', $this->slug);
    })
    ->whereHas('attributes' , function ($attrquery) {
        foreach($this->select_filter_attr as $attr) {
            $attrquery->where('value', $attr);
        }
    })
    ->paginate(100);
```